# Laravel 5 customizing built in login redirect

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware

I am customizing laravel 5's built in login so that it would redirect to three different paths according to the *type* column which i added to the users table, i tried altering the handle function of RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware. but it seems that it always finds the home URI.

here is my edited middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->check() && $this->auth->user()->type == 'patient') {
            // return redirect('/home');
            return 'PATIENT VIEW';
        } elseif ($this->auth->check() && $this->auth->user()->type == 'doctor') {

            return 'DOCTOR VIEW';

        } elseif ($this->auth->check() && $this->auth->user()->type == 'nurse') {

            return 'NURSE VIEW';
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Im new to laravel 5 and i would really appreciate any help and explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectIfAuthenticated` is being misused here. That middleware is for when an authenticated user tries to access a page that should only be accessed by guests. For example, if I am a user and I try to view the login or registration forms, it doesn't let me.

I would not mess with the authentication itself... some of it is easily customizable but what you're trying to do is not. I would just let Laravel authenticate them first and then handle what to do after.

`/home` is the default route users are taken to when they login. Move your if checks to that route controller method. Better yet... if you set things up right you don't need any checks at all.

```php
class HomeController {
    public function index()
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();

        return view($user->type . '.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Now you just need views named `patient/dashboard.blade.php`, `doctor/dashboard.blade.php`, etc. If you have more complex logic then you might want an actual redirect

```
        return redirect('home/' . $user->type);
```

Define routes for each of those types

```
Route::get('home/patient', 'PatientController@dashboard');
Route::get('home/doctor', 'DoctorController@dashboard');
Route::get('home/nurse', 'NurseController@dashboard');
```

And then do whatever you need to in those controller methods.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs in [Authentication section](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#included-authenticating)

Basically what you need is:

- Create the auth routes at **app/Http/routes.php**:

  ```
  // Authentication routes...
  Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
  Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
  ```
- Create the login form view:

  ```
  <!-- resources/views/auth/login.blade.php -->
  <form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
  {!! csrf_field() !!}

  <div>
      Email
      <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
  </div>

  <div>
      Password
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </div>

  <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
  </div>

  <div>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </div>
  </form>
  ```
- Manually Authenticate users **app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php**:

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Auth;
  use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

  class AuthController extends Controller
  {
      /**
       * Handle an authentication attempt.
       *
       * @return Response
       */
      public function authenticate()
      {
          if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
              if (Auth::user()->type == 'patient'){
                  return redirect()->intended('patientDashboard');
              }
              if (Auth::user()->type == 'doctor'){
                  return redirect()->intended('doctorDashboard');
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Or if you want to keep the logic under RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware you could just fix your code:

  ```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
  if ($this->auth->check())
  {
      //we have a logged user check if it's patient
      if($this->auth->user()->type == 'patient'){

        return new RedirectResponse(url('/patient'));

      }else if($this->auth->user()->type == 'doctor'){

        return new RedirectResponse(url('/doctor'));

      }
  }

  return $next($request);
  }
  ```

Also you should check out this [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) package.

Comment: its still using its built in.. i have no idea where to edit its built in functions